# Keeping LinkButton active when clicked

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a couple `LinkButtons` inside my navbar at the top of my page using Bootstrap. When the user clicks the `LinkButton` I want the `LinkButton` to stay active while the user stays on that page, or navigates to a new one. Here is what my `navbar` looks like:

```
   <div style="font-size: 80%; background-color: #ffffff; width: 15%;" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LB_MainPage" runat="server" OnClick="LB_MainPage_Click">Ticket Books Home</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LB_IssueTicket" runat="server" OnClick="LB_IssueTicket_Click">Issue Ticket Book</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LB_Change_TicketBooks" runat="server" OnClick="LB_Change_TicketBooks_Click" >Change Ticket Books</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LB_TicketBook_Reports" runat="server" OnClick="LB_TicketBook_Reports_Click">Search Ticket Books</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LB_MissingTickets" runat="server" OnClick="LB_MissingTickets_Click">Custom Reports</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LB_AddVoidTicket" runat="server" OnClick="LB_AddVoidTicket_Click" >Add Void Ticket</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LB_VoidTickets" runat="server" OnClick="LB_VoidTickets_Click" >Void Tickets</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to style the list by using this CSS code:

```
a:hover{
        border-bottom: solid;
        border-bottom-color: purple;
    }
    a:active{
        color: purple;
        border-bottom: solid;
    }
```

The hover style works great, and so does the active, but when I release the mouse button the active styling does not stay. How can I fix this? If at all possible I would like to do this in code behind (C#) or in CSS.

Here is a JSFiddle of my project:

https://jsfiddle.net/hwcgynr0/

Comment: That requires javascript.

Comment: How would it be done in Javascript if it cannot be done in C# or CSS?

Comment: You need to add a class (or change the CSS) on a "Click". That's the area of Javascript. C# I have no idea but in general, click events are the purview of JS. I''m sure a search of SO would turn you up many options.

Comment: Alright, I will poke around. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a javascript to bind the `active` class to your navbar links as shown here in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/hwcgynr0/2/)

```
$(function () {
            $(".activeBtn").click(function () {
                // remove classes from all
                $(".activeBtn").removeClass("active");
                // add class to the one we clicked
                $(this).addClass("active");
            });
});
```

Comment: So am I to put this on the onclientclick event on my linkbutton?

Comment: No no.... Just keep it within <script></script> tags and keep it on your webpages <head></head> section :) Just make sure you add a <li class="active"></li> to each active li of the respective pages.

Comment: Alright, I put the JQuery code into my script. The page is much slower now to load, but it is not staying highlighted. There does not seem to be any errors thrown though.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with your html, css and js. I will edit it after

Comment: I have never used JSFiddle before. Just figuring it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72606/discussion-between-andrew-lyndem-and-chase-ernst).